# How come you're not suppose to use match_parent in constraint layout?

Tags: java, android

Everything I've read online says to not use match_parent in the Constraint View for the height and width properties because it can't be used and won't work. I have used a constraint layout in a few projects now where I do use match_parent and it does work. Was there an update that I haven't noticed to where it is now able to be used? If not, how come it is working in my situations while it seems it doesn't work at all for other people?

Example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f9d1ff">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:text="Last Entry:"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/saveButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/clearButton"
            android:id="@+id/dataText"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clearButton"
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonscreen"
            android:padding="6dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Clear All"
            android:id="@+id/clearButton"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/saveButton"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/saveButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/saveButton"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonscreen"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Try this constraints for which view you want to make match parent

Comment: That's the thing though, I use those constraints also, but I also use match_parent in the height and width properties. Does it simply ignore those since I implememnt the constraints you listed?

Comment: make layout height and width as 0dp.try this

Comment: So the thing is it works the way I had it already. I was just looking into constraint layouts and everything I've read said match_parent shouldn't work, yet for me it does. I was just wondering why it does work in my context.